# react native - how to save data with sqlite ? because got an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want save data fields from the `axios` and i need to do it with SQLite but got warning .
there is way to solve it ?

in my case i got this when i print the (dbResult) :

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: near "Swift": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO places (artist, image, title, url) VALUES (Taylor Swift, https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61McsadO1OL.jpg, Taylor Swift, https://www.amazon.com/Taylor-Swift/dp/B0014I4KH6);]
- node_modules\expo-sqlite\build\SQLite.js:36:15 in _deserializeResultSet
* [native code]:null in map
- node_modules\expo-sqlite\build\SQLite.js:16:40 in SQLiteDatabase#exec
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

here i create the the database and the columns :

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('places.db');

export const init = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, artist TEXT NOT NULL, image TEXT NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, url TEXT NOT NULL);',
        [],
        () => {
          resolve();
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  });
  return promise;
};

export const insertPlace = (artist, image, title, url) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(
            `INSERT INTO places (artist, image ,title, url) VALUES (${artist}, ${image}, ${title}, ${url});`,
            [],
            (_, result) => {
              resolve(result);
            },
            (_, err) => {
              reject(err);
            }
          );
        });
      });
      return promise;
};

export const fetchPlaces = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM places',
            [],
            (_, result) => {
              resolve(result);
            },
            (_, err) => {
              reject(err);
            }
          );
        });
      });
      return promise;
};
```

and here i use the `axios.get` to get the data and after use the `insertPlace` function to save the fields data into the columns that in the `places.db` i have created but got an error as i mentioned and i dont understand my problem there .

```
import axios from "axios";
import { insertPlace } from "../helpers/db";

export default class WaterQualitySamplesScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  getData = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data,
        });
        //  console.log(res.data);
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          const mediaData = res.data[i];

            const dbResult =  insertPlace(
              mediaData.artist,
              mediaData.image,
              mediaData.title,
              mediaData.url
            );
            console.log(dbResult);

        }
      });
  };

async componentDidMount() {
    this.currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    await this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

    this.getData();
  }

render() {
    return (
    ),
  };
};
```

Comment: maybe try to build in a .catch after the .then in the axios call.

Comment: can you show me how please ?

Comment: I will post a answer check it out but i am not sure if thats the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error here because you are not `awaiting` the subsequent `json()` promise after the initial promise is resolved.

Either you can chain it with `then` or you can use `await` which is more cleaner.

```
this.state = {
  data: "",
  isLoaded: false,
};

getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums"
    );
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log("jsonresponse0", jsonResponse);
    this.setState({ data: jsonResponse, isLoaded: true });
    this.saveDbData();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

saveDbData = async () => {
  const { data, isLoaded } = this.state;
  if (isLoaded) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const mediaData = data[i];
      console.log(mediaData);
      const dbResult = await insertPlace(
        mediaData.artist,
        mediaData.image,
        mediaData.title,
        mediaData.url
      );
      console.log(dbResult);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: 1 . it print me :
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jsonResponse.data.length')
2 . i dont see the console.log(dbResult);

Comment: yes i get the array with the data . but why it doesnt saved in my sqlite table ?

Comment: Alright. I found the error. We were trying to access `response.data.length` even though there is no `data` key on the `response` array. I have updated the code with the correct code.

Comment: its doesnt print me the  console.log(dbResult);

Comment: now it says : [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response]

Comment: Oh sorry, we should be looping through `data` array instead of `response`. Let me change it. I have updated it. Now it should work.

Comment: now it says :

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: near "Swift": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO places (artist, image, title, url) VALUES (Taylor Swift, https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61McsadO1OL.jpg, Taylor Swift, https://www.amazon.com/Taylor-Swift/dp/B0014I4KH6);]

Comment: Alright, to debug instead of looping through the array, can you just do this?  `const mediaData = data[0];
      console.log(mediaData);
      const dbResult = await insertPlace(
        mediaData.artist,
        mediaData.image,
        mediaData.title,
        mediaData.url
      );
      console.log(dbResult);` outside the for loop?

Comment: i need some help please

Answer (score 0):

```
  getData = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data,
        });
        //  console.log(res.data);
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          const mediaData = res.data[i];

            const dbResult =  insertPlace(
              mediaData.artist,
              mediaData.image,
              mediaData.title,
              mediaData.url
            );
            console.log(dbResult);

        }
      })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))          // this is the catch
  };
```

It also could be that a .then() is missing to resolve the issue.